# Modifying Realm values swift using map

Tags: swift, realm

I want to modify model data in Realm database in Swift App. Here is my code:

```
try! realm.write {
    realm.objects(CompanyModel.self).map({ (model)  in
        model.isSelected = true
    })
}
```

Idea is simple, iterate through models and change isSelected bool property to true. But look like it not work. Why?

Comment: Why does it "look like it not work"? do you get any errors?

Comment: @Scriptable i did inspect database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't use `map` if you want to modify the original `Results` instance and hence the model objects stored in your Realm. 'map' is not a mutating function, it iterates through your array (or in this case, `Results`), applies a transformation to each element of the sequence, then returns a new sequence containing the results of the transformation.

What you would actually need is the `forEach` function, which only iterates through the elements of an `Array` and executes the closure for each element,but doesn't return a new `Array`. I am currently not able to test it, but I since `forEach` is a member function of `Array` and not of `NSFastEnumeration`, from which `Results` inherits, I think you cannot use `forEach` on a `Results` instance, so you need to use a regular for loop to do this.

```
try! realm.write {
    for model in realm.objects(CompanyModel.self) {
        model.isSelected = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Pasztor thanks, i just wondered if i can use .map .filter and similiar functions to modify existing objects.

Comment: Glad I could help. You can't, since neither `map`, nor `filter` are mutating functions. They both return a new collection with the results.

Comment: Pazstor i ended up with something like that myArr = myArr.map{..}.filter{..}

Comment: If you want to use the auto-updating property of `Results`, don't do that. That will create and return a new collection instead of modifying the original one, which is not the behaviour you want to have in this case. Moreover, you can always combine subsequent `map` and `filter` operations into a single `flatMap`, which improves the performance of your code.

Comment: Pasztor by using myCollection = myCollection.map{..} i do change pointer of myCollection var?

Comment: You are right, you can assign the return value of `map` to your original variable instead of assigning it to a new variable. However, for large datasets this is unwanted, because `map` will create an array the same size as your original array, so the memory complexity of your implementation will most likely be twice than if you just iterated through the dataset in a for loop.